# Правила разработки сайта

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, я только учусь делать сайты. Мне совсем не нравится когда первая страница уходит сильно вниз с разной информацией,когда надо долго скролить вниз до какого-то блока. Ну, использование якоря, тоже не совсем то(как по мне). Такой вопрос, нормальная ли практика создавать блоке на одном уровне и управлять их видимостью с помощью css. Спасибо за ответ заранее!)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сверстать для всех устройств нормально то почему и нет? Тут пожалуй дело вкуса.Но ! просто нужно знать историю появления сайтов полотен. Чаше всего их легче сверстать под все устройства. Это первое. И второе поисковики любят полотна, пробежал по готовому HTML и все считал. Да при скрытии части html с помощью css html тоже может присутствовать,но было время когда подобными методами пользовались желающие обмануть поисковики и писали куча текста туда, а потом прятали. В итоге от туда и пошла мода на сайты полотна, что такой точно поисковику придется по вкусу.Ведь как выглядит сайт на самом деле это дело вкуса, а вот на каком он месте в поиске это дело бизнеса. Так что оцени все эти моменты, и прими решения.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!